# Anaconda new environment error: Paths don't have the same drive

Tags: anaconda, data-science

I want to create a new environment in Anaconda, but I get an error:

> ValueError("Paths don't have the same drive")

```
file "Q:\CI_Anlisten\Users\lkh004\Conda\lib\ntpath.py, line 804 in commonpath raise ValueError("Paths don't have the same drive)
```